# Edited css not updated in XAMPP

Tags: css, joomla-3.3.x, xampp

I am new to Joomla and just downloaded a template (from my company) and deployed it on XAMPP.

When I try to edit the CSS and refresh the page, the css does not get updated. I have tried clearing the cache and refreshing, but no such luck.

Comment: Welcome to JSE. Which template are you using? Which CSS file are you trying to edit? Where did you edit it?

Comment: i am using a custom template from my company, i inspected the element in the browser and edited the respective css file in my localhost

Comment: Welcome to JSE, please take our [tour].  Have you seen this? [Xampp and Ampps don't reload files when changed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26308810/2943403)  And this page talks about cache config settings: https://www.joomlashack.com/blog/joomla/guided-tour-your-joomla-configurationphp-file/  And here is Joomla docs page regarding caching: https://docs.joomla.org/Cache#:~:text=Changing%20an%20article%20(or%20other,and%20press%20the%20Delete%20button.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that your edit file being saved?  ...this is a "sanity check" request for confirmation from you.  Is the css file modification timestamp changed in your system?

Comment: Yes, i just checked once more and i can see the timestamp, i even opened the file again to check if the changes were made and it was there

Answer (score 0):

Joomla's default Protostar template includes CSS files with

```
JHtml::_('stylesheet', 'template.css', array('version' => 'auto', 'relative' => true));
```

The `['version' => 'auto']` adds a **media version MD5 hash** as token to the file. The media version is regenerated by Joomla whenever anything is installed on the Joomla instance. See https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Adding_JavaScript_and_CSS_to_the_page#.24options_and_.24attributes_Parameters

The media version **does NOT change** when you make **changes in your CSS**. You could add your own timestamp to force a browser to re-load the CSS instead using it from cache.

In your template's index.php you could add something like:

```
use Joomla\CMS\HTML\HTMLHelper;

HTMLHelper::_(
    'stylesheet',
    'your-css-file.css',
    [
        'version'  => filemtime(JPATH_THEMES
            . '/your-template/css/your-css-file.css'),
        'relative' => true
    ]
);
```